# Php Regular expression for change the word that is outside the anchor, not inside the anchor

Tags: php, regex, anchor

I have a regular expression below
**'preg_replace ('/(abc)(?!([^\"]*\">[^<]*)?</a>)/','$1', $content)'**
 and i want if **abc** is inside the anchor tag then it would not replaced but if it is out side the anchor tag then it must be replaced
E.g
**`<a href="any@domain.com" title="adada" target="sdada">he is abc guy</a> is an abc guy etc...`**
In this condition the **abc** inside the anchor tag would not replaced but the **abc** outside the tag must be replaced

Answer (score 0):

You can use this that avoid the content inside links, script, style, comments, cdata and the tags attributes:

```
$regex = '~(?:<(a|script|style)\b.*?</\1>|<!--.*?-->|<!\[CDATA\[.*?]]>|<.*?>)'
       . '(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|abc~si';

$result = preg_replace($regex, 'HiHa!!', $content);
```

When a substring matches the subpattern before the `(*SKIP)` backtracking control verb, and if the subpattern fails after the `(*SKIP)`, the regex engine don't try to match the substring with another part of the pattern (the another part here is `abc`) but continue after the substring. `(*FAIL)` forces the subpattern to fail.

The `s` modifier allows the dot to match newlines.

The pattern can be optimized to:

```
$regex = '~(?><(a|script|style)\b(?>[^<]++|<(?!/\1>))*+</\1>|'
       . '<!--(?>[^-]++|-(?!->))*+-->|'
       . '<!\[CDATA\[(?>[^]]++|](?!]>))*+]]>|<[^>]*+>)++(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|abc~si';
```

**A more appropriate method**

Since you are trying to modify an html document you can use DOMDocument and XPath that are tools designed for this kind of task:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$textnodes = $xpath->query('//text()[not(ancestor::a)]');

foreach ($textnodes as $textnode) {
    $textnode->nodeValue = str_replace('abc', 'HiHa!!', $textnode->nodeValue);
}

$result = $doc->saveHTML();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: actually in my scenario when my given text 'abc' is inside the anchor tag like 'my <a href="ad@domain.com">name is abc</a>' then this "abc" would not be changed but if my given text like this "my name is abc", then this abc must be changed with a link like this "my name is <a href="asd@domain.com">abc</a>"...